Do we need the [analytic-languages] tag?
The tag analytic-languages is currently without a tag description and does not have any questions asked using that tag.
My question is, what is the purpose of that tag, or should we just burninate it/merge it with another tag?

Tags that are not used on any questions, do not have usage guidance (also called a tag wiki excerpt), and are not a synonym of another existing tag will be automatically deleted by the system, with a process that runs once a day or so.
As long as no new questions are tagged with this tag, it'll automatically disappear and we don't have to do anything at all to it.
